# Has anyone tried running macro embedded in a microsoft word document from Python

Tags: python-3.x, win32com

I have a macro in word 2013, that removes white spaces and adjust page width size to ensure the tables fit.
Currently, in order to make these changes to the document, the user needs to run the macro first, and only after running it, when they print the document, the changes are ensured.

I would like to automate the part of running the macro

This is for formating the word doc to ensure that the tables in the document fit the page.

```
import os
import time
import win32com.client
from docx import Document


macro_to_run = 'PostProcess'
document = 
   wordapp.Documents.Open('C:\\Users\\sarvesa\\Downloads\\test_xrd.doc')
wordapp.run(document, macro_to_run)
document.save
document.close
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename_change.py", line 12, in 
    wordapp.run(document, macro_to_run)
  File "C:\Users\sarvesa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in **getattr**
    ret = self.*oleobj*.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', "'Run' is not a property.", 'wdmain11.chm', 25342, -2146822426), None)

Comment: how do you define `wordapp`? if it is what I think according to your current code, try `wordapp.Application.Run(macro_to_run)`

Answer (score 0):

provided "wordapp" is the instance of word, called like this:

```
wordapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Word.application")
```

then there are 2 issues:
1) you are missing "Application" 
2) These methods are all inherited from VBA, which means you need to use that syntax. This includes casing!
I too had to google a lot of this information and compile it to a working script. I recommend reading some VBA tutorials as well.

Try:

```
wordapp.Application.Run(macroName)
```

Edit:
Also your "macro_to_run" might be insufficient.
You need to not only specify the module name, but also the Sub you want to run:
Like `"Normal.Module1.SubName"`